# PBX and Web App communication

Tags: java, javascript, sip, asterisk

I have a Web application running on Chrome.
Now I need to communicate with an Asterisk PBX / FreePBX in order to fetch inside the web app the caller ids of those who call in the PBX.
The PBX is in a standalone computer connected in the same network as the other computers that run my web app.

How is this possible?
Should I create a Java Applet to fetch somehow the caller ids via SIP?
Or should I use Javascript in order to query SIP data?

I need to know how and if this is possible so that I will be able to hire the correct developer.
Thank you

Comment: Will I be able to do this directly with Javascript without a Java Applet? Does anyone have experience with SIP and PBX?

Comment: you have to use AJAX or WebSockets for transmitting the information from the Backend to the Frontend

Answer (score 1):

You should look at using the Asterisk Manager Interface (AMI). It generates events and also can respond to commands.

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+manager+API

There are wrapper libraries for many programming languages: PHP, Node, ASP.NET and so on. Since you didn't elaborate on your requirements, that's all I can answer!

While you could technically do it from Javascript, you would be exposing your PBX address, and Manager user/password on a webpage. Normally for that you need to develop a proxy: an application running on the server that acts as a proxy between your PBX and your web users.

PBX <-- Manager API --> Server side Proxy <---> Web App

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Let me elaborate a little bit in order to be able to help a little bit more. There Asterisk PBX will run on a computer that will be connected locally on Switch. So will the computers that will run the web app. The web app works with javascript.
Also, when you say exposing the PBX address and user/password could you please explain to whom? I mean the asterisk PBX will exist inside a local FAST FOOD store and it will have 2 ISDN land lines connected to it. The goal of the whole thing is to be able to grab the caller ids and display them in my javascript web app. Thanks

Comment: Hi, my comment still holds. If you're not a developer, hire someone profficient on nodejs or PHP + javascript and they'll be able to sort it out quite easily. The term "javascript web app" is a broad concept! Anyway google AMI examples and see what's already done. ;)

Comment: Hiring someone is the only solution of course. That is what I am going to do, but the problem is that I need to understand some basic things in order to hire the right person. So after the Asterisk PBX installation that will be done by the company I will buy it, will I need a javascript developer?

Comment: Sorry anestis, but this kind of consulting is exactly what you will be paying that company for. Find a reseller that knows about integrations. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using asterisk 12 or newer, you can also use ARI (asterisk restful interface) as well. There is a Java wrapper for it here: https://github.com/l3nz/ari4java

For the API documentation see: https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Getting+Started+with+ARI